# Ibus anthy - removing given input modes

Tags: 14.04, ibus, japanese

For the Anthy engine in Ibus, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> to switch between entering text with hiragana, full width katakana, half width katakana, normal width latin and wide latin.

I want to remove some of these (e.g. the half width katakana option and the wide latin option) as I never use them and it makes cycling between the ones I need slower. I have looked into the Ibus anthy settings but could not find anything. Searching AskUbuntu also found nothing similar.

Note: I am using Ubuntu 14.04

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Select Anthy, then Preferences-Anthy. In the Setup window go to the Key Binding tab.

[image]

Normally the shortcut listed for "hiragana-mode", katakana-mode, etc. is [ ] for no shortcut.

Doubleclick on an item and you can add a shortcut key description. I used Ctrl+H and Ctrl+K (of course use whichever you want). Then you can use those keys directly to select the kana mode, rather than cycling through the options.

Comment: Thanks user3169! Although this is a useful workaround, I will keep the question open as your answer does not help me remove the modes from the list (or at least give indication that the modes are not removable).

Comment: Why do you want to remove them? The number of key presses is the same.

Comment: Removing them reduces the potential of the new keyboard shortcuts conflicting with other programs or my window manager. Also, less cognitive load (only have to remember one shortcut to change the input mode).